# Position an element directly next to stackable menu

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm just starting with Semantic UI and would like to create a theme similar to ["Jumbotron" at Semantic UI Forest](http://semantic-ui-forest.com/templates/bootstrap/jumbotron/).

The major difference is that I want the navigtaion menu to be responsive so I added the `stackable` class. The menu itself gets stacked when I change the screen size but it hides the "jumbotron". I want the jumbotron positioned directly next to the navigation bar in either mode, stacked or unstacked.

Please check out the [example on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPwxzV) and this screenshot. The red area shall always be aligned below the menu.

What am I missing here?

[image: sample screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codepen example and Semantic UI Jumbotron examples are almost identical. The difference is that you have missed the inline css on ui.grid.row which has 2.5 em margin. It shifts the row of massive message down.

```
  .ui.grid.message .row {
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  }
```

With this solution you need 6em margin-top for row what is bad. On desktops there will be too much space between menu and jumbotron container. On mobile phones to less. Another solution is following:

```
<div class="ui top fixed stackable inverted massive menu" style:"position:relative !important;">

<div class="ui grid massive message" style:"margin-top:0em !important;">
```